# How do I get these social icons to be straight centered on the page on all browsers?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, responsive-design

Link to website: foxweb.marist.edu/users/kf79g/contact.php

This is it. The last step I have to fix before deploying my website and finally finishing it. But I do not know how to resolve this issue. On medium and small screens, I am having a lot of trouble with my social icons. I want the whole thing on medium and small devices to be centered and 100% responsive. I have tried making a container to make them responsive, but no matter what I do, it always looks messy in IE 7-10. The icons are moving to the next line instead of staying on one line evenly as the page width gets smaller and smaller. I tried adjusting the margins, but that didn't helps since that ruined my center attribute for the whole page. I simply do not know what to do or how to fix this issue. If anybody can help me I would really appreciate it.

Visual representation of problem (IE):

http://tinypic.com/r/nla7eq/5

What I want it to look like (modern browsers):

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=vp9gg7&s=5

HTML:

```
<h2> Social networks </h2><br/>

                        <div id = "center_icons">
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/lenny.pfautsch" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook" style="margin:1px;"></a> 

                            <a href="https://plus.google.com/113122168458946246215/posts" target="_blank"><img src="images/google-plus.png" alt="google plus" style="margin:1px;"></a>

                            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/leonard-pfautsch/53/b34/1a2" target="_blank"><img src="images/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" style="margin:1px;"></a>

                            <a href="https://github.com/LeonardPfautsch" target="_blank"><img src="images/github.png" alt="github" style="margin:1px;"></a>
                        </div>
                    <br/>

                    </div>

            </section>      


Main CSS:   

    #details_section {
        max-width:100%;
        float:left;
        margin-right:20px;
    }


Large screens:    

    #details_section {
        width:320px;
    }




Medium screens:    

    #center{
    width: 450px;
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }

    #center_icons{
    width: 213px; /*this value is changing for IE and chrome*/
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }



Small screens:    

    #center{
    width: 220px;
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      max-width:100%;
    }

    #center_icons{
    width: 214px; /*this value is changing for IE and chrome*/
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      max-width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: Please, show us only the relevant code. No one will read this too long extract.

Comment: okay give me a minute and I will make it simpler

Comment: I have made the appropriate changes.

Comment: Have you tried to apply img{border:0;}. IE tend to apply stupid border to images.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa I tried what you said and that did not change anything.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa do you think resizing the actual images in my folder and making them smaller would resolve the issue? I tried surrounding the whole thing in another div called #center img{width:20%; max-width 100%;} This made the whole container responsive but messes up my centeredness.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could also remove spaces between "=", and use " instead of '.

```
<div id = "center">
<div id='details_section'>
```

should be

```
<div id="center">
<div id="details_section">
```

You should also indicate the image size somewhere.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="center_icons">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/lenny.pfautsch" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook" width="40" height="40"></a>

<a href="https://plus.google.com/113122168458946246215/posts" target="_blank"><img src="images/google-plus.png" alt="google plus" width="40" height="40"></a>

<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/leonard-pfautsch/53/b34/1a2" target="_blank"><img src="images/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" width="40" height="40"></a>

<a href="https://github.com/LeonardPfautsch" target="_blank"><img src="images/github.png" alt="github" width="40" height="40"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

And a simpler CSS would be:

```
div {border: 1px red solid;padding: 5px}   /*this is only for us to see it when testing*/

#container {
        text-align:center;
    }

    #center_icons{
    width: 214px; /*this value is changing for IE and chrome*/
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      max-width:100%;
    }
```

Check it working here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAjzo

Comment: How this answer the question?

Comment: I also removed the  style="margin:1px;" from your images html, you can add it on the css if needed.

Comment: You sir, have led me in the right direction and I am one step closer to deploying my website. I was able to fix the icons. Thank you so much for your effort. All I have left is fixing the form on the page because that is not centering evenly for some reason. I will ask another question on here about that, if you can help me with that too I would be forever grateful like how I am right now. Thank you soo much!

Comment: You try the same process to different elements: use a div to work as a container, to put your content in the center, for example `#container {text-align:center}` and another one to hold your content in the center, for example `#formcontent {width:250px; margin:auto; text-align:left}`

Comment: sorry @MohammadAreebSiddiqui and aurelio if the response was incomplete at that time.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `<center> </center>` in code instead of Div id "center".

Comment: What do you mean by this? Do you mean style it internally in the html instead of externally linking it?

Comment: @user2521978 Oh my God, don't! center is an absolutely deprecated tag!

Comment: I get a ton of html5 validation errors if I do this. I want to keep my page error free.

Comment: @Aurelio De Rosa I am well aware thank you though for reminding me.

Answer (score -1):

you need to change your CSS properties just measure your screen co-ordinates and put it in margin or you can use HTML5 to solve this problem.

Comment: What do you mean using tag? How can I use HTML5 to solve this? Can you please elaborate on your answer and perhaps provide an example to what you mean? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: i'mean just use HTML5 Canvas it put your social icons on it. to learn more about canvas go here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp